# Implementing ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, itemlistener

i've been having problem in the itemStateChanged section. when I compiled the program i get the "cannot find variable" error and I can't seem to find out where I did wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thank You.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Postcode extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Melaka Postcode");
        fr.setSize(240, 125);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Postcode() {
        String[] code = {"75450", "77000", "78000"};
        JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("Postcode");
        JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("District?");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(code);
        cb.addItemListener(this);
        Font f = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14);
        lb2.setFont(f);
        p1.add(lb1);
        p1.add(cb);
        p2.add(lb2);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (code.getSelectedItem().equals("75450")) {
            lb2.setText = "Bukit Beruang";
        }
        if (code.getSelectedItem().equals("77000")) {
            lb2.setText = "Jasin";
        }
        if (code.getSelectedItem().equals("75450")) {
            lb2.setText = "Alor Gajah";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Java will just say "cannot find variable" without point where the variable is missing, please whole stack trace or error line? Which is in ItemStateChanged, `code` is not declared in local scope, make it a property of your class and use `this.code instead`

Answer (score 5):

Your code had a lot of problems, so I have to post here the solution entirely. The fixes:

Declared the variables as member variables

Called `getSelectedItem()` on the `combobox`, not on the array of String

Use the `JLabel.setText()` correctly

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Postcode extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    String[] code = { "75450", "77000", "78000" };

    JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("Postcode");

    JLabel lb2 = new JLabel("District?");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

    JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(code);

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Melaka Postcode");
        fr.setSize(240, 125);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public Postcode() {
        cb.addItemListener(this);

        Font f = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14);

        lb2.setFont(f);

        p1.add(lb1);
        p1.add(cb);

        p2.add(lb2);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("75450"))
            lb2.setText("Bukit Beruang");
        if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("77000"))
            lb2.setText("Jasin");
        if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("75450"))
            lb2.setText("Alor Gajah");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In itemStateChanged, you are calling `.getSelectedItem()` on a variable that is not known to the scope of `itemStateChanged()`, secondly I don't think you want to call this method on a String array (`code`), I think you use `e.getItem()` or `e.getItemSelectable` instead.

See the documentation on [ItemEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Just found a similar weird behaviour in my own code. Try to rewrite your code using a switch statement instead of multiple if statements.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
switch(cb.getSelectedItem().toString()){

case "75450":
lb2.setText("Bukit Beruang");
break;

case "77000":
lb2.setText("Jasin");
break;
case "75451":                 //Changed this into a unique value
lb2.setText("Alor Gajah");    //because the switch statements 
break;                        //will throw error when supplied
}                                 //with repeated values


}
```

Let me know if it worked for you!